# Ubuntu - Curl X Times Repeat

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, curl

I Want to use curl for 100 times repeat using terminal.

I try make something but it's not working.

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do curl -0 mywebpageurl done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a semi colon after the URL!

You have: `for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do curl -0 mywebpageurl done`

It should be: `for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do curl -0 mywebpageurl; done`

Comment: Thank you so much really so easy problem.I need sleep :)  Now here 4:34 AM :)

Comment: No problem dude! I totally know the feeling